# Select an item from a list of object of any type when using tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2

Given a list of instances of class `A`, `[A() for _ in range(5)]`, I want to randomly select one of them (see the following code for an example)

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self):
        return self.a
def f():
    a_list = [A(i) for i in range(5)]
    a = a_list[random.randint(0, 5)]()
    return a

f()
```

Is there is a way to decorate `f` with `@tf.function` without changing what `f` does and without calling all items in `a_list`?

Note that directly decorating `f` with `@tf.function` without any other changing to the above code is infeasible as it will always return the same result. Also, I know that this can be achieved by calling all elements in `a_list` first and then index them using `tf.gather_nd`. But this will incur a large amount of overhead if calling an object of type `A` involves a deep neural network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on the same thing at the moment. Here's what I've got so far. If anyone knows a better way I'd be interested to hear it too. When I run it on an expensive call it is appropriately faster than if I compute and return all of the values.

```
@tf.function
def f2():
    a_list = [A(i) for i in range(5)]
    idx = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], maxval=4), tf.int32)
    return tf.switch_case(idx, a_list)
```

For a speed comparison I made the call method of A expensive matrix algebra. Then consider an alternate function which invokes every function:

```
@tf.function
def f3():
    a_list = [A(i) for i in range(40)]
    results = [a() for a in a_list]
    return results
```

Running f2 with 40 elements: 0.42643 seconds

Running f3 with 40 elements: 14.9153 seconds

So that looks to be right about exactly the expected 40x speedup for only choosing one branch.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPotter. Thanks for the answer. It's great.