# Select item from list of objects of any type in tensorflow 2.x in tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

I have a list of tensorflow models and I want to select one of them using an index. However, if the call happens in a function decorated with @tf.function, I cannot make it work. Has someone found a way to do this?

[Select an item from a list of object of any type when using tensorflow 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838440/select-an-item-from-a-list-of-object-of-any-type-when-using-tensorflow-2-x) is a similar question, but they do not pass arguments to the function. Unfortunately, with tf.switch_case, the list elements need to be callable and will be called on execution

```
class an_object():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self, b):
        print("called ", self.a, b)

@tf.function
def a_function(a_list):
    idx = tf.constant(1)
    # return a_list[idx] # longer error / bug message. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
    # return tf.switch_case(idx,a_list) # TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
    
a_list = [an_object(1), an_object(2), an_object(3)]       
x = a_function(a_list)
```