# Simultaneously training multiple tensorflow models

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

For a multi-agent RL problem, I am training multiple models simultaneously. Currently my structure looks as follows:

```py
class testmodel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)
        self.l3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = "softmax")

    def call(self, x):
        y = self.l1(x)
        y = self.l2(y)
        y = self.l3(y)
        return y

class MARL():
    def __init__(self, nAgents, input_shape):
        self.nAgents = nAgents
        self.list_of_actors = list()
        self.list_of_optimizers = list()
        for agent in range(nAgents):
            self.list_of_actors.append(testmodel())
            self.list_of_optimizers.append(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001))
            self.list_of_actors[agent].build(input_shape = input_shape)

    @tf.function
    def learn_for_loop(self):
        x = np.random.random_sample((20,)).tolist()
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, 0)

        for agent in range(self.nAgents):
            with tf.GradientTape() as g:

                y_hat = self.list_of_actors[agent](x)
                loss = y_hat - tf.constant([0.,0])

            grads = g.gradient(loss, self.list_of_actors[agent].trainable_variables)
            self.list_of_optimizers[agent].apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.list_of_actors[agent].trainable_variables))

    @tf.function
    def learn_tf_loop(self):

        def body(i,x):
            with tf.GradientTape() as g:

                y_hat = self.list_of_actors[i](x) ### throws error a)
                loss = y_hat - tf.constant([0.,0])

            grads = g.gradient(loss, self.list_of_actors[i].trainable_variables)
            self.list_of_optimizers[agent].apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.list_of_actors[agent].trainable_variables)) ### throws error b)

            return (tf.add(i,1),x)

        def condition(i,x):
            return tf.less(i,self.nAgents)

        i = tf.constant(0)
        x = np.random.random_sample((20,)).tolist()
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, 0)

        r = tf.while_loop(condition, body, (i,x))
```

If I now compare the runtimes on my CPU, I get the following results:

```py
test_instance = MARL(10, (1,20))

tic = time.time()   
for _ in range(100):
    test_instance.learn_for_loop()
print(time.time() - tic)
# without @tf.function: ~ 7s
# with @tf.function: ~ 3.5s # cut runtime by half, GREAT

tic = time.time()   
for _ in range(100):
    test_instance.learn_tf_loop()
print(time.time() - tic)
# without @tf.function: ~ 7s
# with @tf.function: super problematic
```

In my understanding, the more tensorflowy "learn_tf_loop" should be faster than "learn_for_loop", especially for larger models and when using a GPU. I expect these effects to become apparent especially with the tf.function decorator. Unfortunately, this leads to errors like a) "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor" and b) "ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call." These errors have been dealt with at a) [Select an item from a list of object of any type when using tensorflow 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838440/select-an-item-from-a-list-of-object-of-any-type-when-using-tensorflow-2-x) and b) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27120 respectively, but unfortunately, I can't make these solutions work as I a) need to give input to my models when calling them and b) do not want to create n number of seperate functions for my n Agents. How can I make "learn_tf_loop" work WITH the tf.function decorator? I think it boils down to the following two questions:

### tl;dr:

- How can I store the models in a way that they are still accessible in graph mode with a tensor?
- How can I train multiple models simultaneously in graph mode?

Comment: Use `tf.distribute.Strategy` to distribute training across multiple GPUs or multiple machines. You can execute your programs eagerly, or in a graph mode using `tf.function`. For more information on the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training). Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TFer, thanks for your respornse: unfortunately this does not really solve my problems. My problem does not lie in distributing training across multiple GPUs but in the above mentioned shortcomings when training multiple models in a single program.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I had a similar question so here's what I did. I implemented my solution for the data collection phase (having all agents produce their action feeded with a common timestep) in order to provide it to the step function of my environment (I'm using the tf-agents framework but you could workout something similar). Here's how I did it:
I used a tf.Variable to store the current timestep (actually 2 Variables, one for the float members of timestep concatenated (discount, reward and observation) and one for the int members (only the step type). Afterwards I created a dict with ints as keys denoting the agent's id (0 to number_of_agents -1) and lambda functions producing each agents action with the time step stored in the Variable (of course you need to convert it back to a TimeStep nested structure). The reason you need to do this is because tf.switch_case doesn't take arguments to pass on to the Callables. Afterwards you just use a map_fn with parallel calls and feed a tensor of agent id's to a function that uses tf.case_switch to choose one of the dict members but only after you have updated the tf.Variables with the new time_step.
I don't know if the code is parallelized by tensorflow automatically (it should in theory) but it's a solution that uses only tensorflow commands without any python multi-threading.

Here's the code of my policy wrapper simplified (it shouldn't make much sense but focus on the basic parts: the dict the tf.Variables and the map_fn calling the tf.case_switch):

```
class MyPolicyWrapper(TFPolicy)
    def __init__(self,
             policy_list: List[TFPolicy],#a list of the agent's policies
             ):

    self._policy_list = policy_list
    self._num_of_agents = len(policy_list)
    self._time_step_float_tensors = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((14 + self._num_of_agents,), tf.float32))
    self._time_step_int_tensor = tf.Variable(0)
    self._agent_id_tensor = tf.cast(tf.range(self._num_of_agents), tf.float32)
    self._dict = {i: lambda: policy_list[i].action(self._get_time_step(),                                                      ()) for i in range(self._num_of_agents)}


#kept this function to remind that Variables only store tensors which you 
#might need to convert back to the necessary nested sequence (TimeStep here)
def _get_time_step(self):
    float_members = self._time_step_float_tensors
    int_members = self._time_step_int_tensor
    observation = tf.expand_dims(float_members[:13], axis=0)
    discount = tf.expand_dims(float_members[13], axis=0)
    reward = tf.expand_dims(float_members[14:], axis=0)
    step_type = tf.expand_dims(int_members, axis=0)
    return TimeStep(observation=observation,
                    reward=reward,
                    discount=discount,
                    step_type=step_type)

@tf.function
def _action(self, time_step: ts.TimeStep,
                  policy_state: types.NestedTensor,
                  seed: Optional[types.Seed] = None) -> policy_step.PolicyStep:
    float_time_step_members = tf.concat((time_step.observation[0],
                                         time_step.discount,
                                         time_step.reward[0]), axis=0)
    int_time_step_members = time_step.step_type[0]
    self._time_step_float_tensors.assign(float_time_step_members)
    self._time_step_int_tensor.assign(int_time_step_members)
    action_tensor = tf.map_fn(lambda id: tf.switch_case(tf.cast(id, tf.int32),
                                                        self._policy_action_dict).action,
                              self._agent_id_tensor,
                              parallel_iterations=self._num_of_agents)[0]

    return policy_step.PolicyStep(action=action_tensor)
```